# Retrieve json data based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json data in following format

```
 {"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]}
```

i have a select tag, if the value selected from a select box equal to "`Jack`" then it should print the data `"my1@email.com","US"`

select box on change function is

```
       function printDataOf(val){

        now if selectd value is Jack
        alert()   // should alert my1@email.com
        alert()   // should alert US
```

how do i do it?

Comment: `alert(data[val][0])`

Comment: @thg435 That is not working :(

Comment: replace "data" with whatever your JSON array is called.

Comment: @thg435 I was making a silly mistake, while doing I have written it as `alert(json_obj[Jack][0]);` instead of `alert(json_obj["Jack"][0]);`.  You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it;

```
printDataOf('Jack');

function printDataOf(val) {

    var data = '{"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]}';

    var match = JSON.parse(data)[val];
    var email = match[0];
    var country = match[1];

    alert(email);
    alert(country);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The onchange function will not be able to receive the actual value.  You can pass the select object (as 'this') though.

```
<select onchange="printDataOf(this)">
    <option/>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="Rob">Rob</option>
</select>
```

Now in the handler you can get the actual selected value and display the desired data.

```
var json_obj =  {"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]};

function printDataOf(val){
  var Mval = $(val).val();
  alert(json_obj[Mval][0]);
  alert(json_obj[Mval][1]);
}
```

It would be wise to check for existence of Mval in the json object.  If it is not there you will receive an error.  I didn't do it here to keep it simple.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7p7bc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    function check( json_obj ) 
{
    return json_obj[0] == 'Jack'
}
```

if you're using jquery, also try this:

```
json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON( json_obj.responseText );
```

To examine what you really got, use firebug's debugger

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change `json` with your actual object:

```
function printDataOf(val)
{
   for (name in json)
   {
      if (name == val)
      {
          alert(json.name[0]);
          alert(json.name[1]);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you needed,

```
var result = {"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]};

function printDataOf(val){
   var data = JSON.parse(result);

   var selected = data[val];
   var selected_arr = selected.split(',');

   //now if selectd value is Jack
   alert(selected_arr[0])   // should alert my1@email.com
   alert(selected_arr[1])   // should alert US
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (key in jsonobject) {
   alert(jsonobject[val][0];
   alert(jsonobject[val][1];
   alert(jsonobject[val][2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop Json data and then compare and print . Using jquery...

```
  var data = {"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]}
var selecteVal="Jack";

$.each(data,function(key,index){
       if (key==selecteVal){
            alert(data[key][0])
             alert(data[key][1])
            }    
       });
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tH6wk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  var data = {"Jack":["my1@email.com","US"],"Rob":["rob@email.com","UK"]}
  var selecteVal="Jack";

  if(typeof(data[selecteVal])!='undefined'){
     alert(data[selecteVal][0]);//my1@email.com
     alert(data[selecteVal][1]);//US
  }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tH6wk/2/)**

Comment: Yo don't need to run loop